# Issues with if string validation loop

Tags: c++, string, debugging, if-statement, nested

I'm working on a validation if loop which checks for pipes at the beginning and end and makes sure there are 32 valid characters (valid chars are : and |)

I'm wondering why my program is not reading the if statement correctly for a 32 character input. Here is what I have so far.

```
void checkitout(string validate)
{
   string check;
   check = validate;

   if ((check.length() == 31) && 
       (check.substr(0,1) == "|") && 
       (check.substr(31,1) == "|"))
   { 
     cout << "is this running?";

     for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
     {   
       cout << "for loop running";

       if (!(check.substr(i, 1) == ":") || !(check.substr(i, 1) == "|"))
       {
         cout << "Please enter acceptable barcode.";
         return;
       }
     }
   }
   else
   {
     cout << "else Please enter acceptable barcode";
   }
}
```

I'm new to this but I think I'm on the right track. The couts are to test to see if the loop is working. It goes right to the else state. Here is a sample input

||:|:::|:|:||::::::||:|::|:::|||

As always, any thoughts on how to do this better are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It's well defined with C++11 iirc? Should return a non-modifiable null char.

Comment: It's a total of 32 characters so that should be 0-31 right?

Comment: @user657267 sorry about that I've edited the text

Comment: You string length is 32 instead of 31..

Comment: If the string is 32 characters long, why do you check if its 31 characters long?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `pos == size` is valid for `substr` and returns an empty string.

Comment: @user657267 Ah yeah you're right. Too early still for me! :)

Comment: We know what you have and that there is an issue with it. What is the issue? (i.e. what do you expect to happen and what happens instead?) You also say "any thoughts on how to do this better are greatly appreciated"; Do what? i.e. we know what the function does, because we can read the code. What did you want it to do? ("check it out" is not much of an algorithm description)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Good catch. Not the only problem apparently though.

Comment: Step through the code, line by line, in a debugger.

Comment: @utnapistim sorry I had to remove my comments due to my unfamiliarity of embedding text. Point taken as well with naming functions more appropriately. This function is suppose to check for a first and last char of an input (example provided), confirms there are the correct number of characters (32) and confirm that all characters are a | and :

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it builds. It's an issue with this specific if loop.

Comment: `if (!(check.substr(i, 1) == ":") && !(check.substr(i, 1) == "|"))` use logical AND. OR is the wrong condition at this point.

Comment: Based on the cout << "for loop running" it's not even getting to the nested if/for statement, right?

Comment: Have you tried printing out the length of the string? There could be non-printable characters.

Answer (score 1):

Your string has a lenght of 32, thus the if-condition is false because of check.length() == 31.
Also the if-condition in your loop needs an "&&" instead of an "||", since you want it to be neither "|" nor ":" to be an unacceptable barcode.

Changes are marked in bold.

```
void checkitout(string validate)
{
   string check;
   check = validate;
   string one = check.substr(4,1);
   cout << (check.substr(4,1) == one) << endl;

   if ((check.length() == **32**) &&
       (check.substr(0,1) == "|") &&
       (check.substr(31,1) == "|"))
   {
     cout << "is this running?";

     for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
     {
       cout << "for loop running";

       if (!(check.substr(i, 1) == ":") **&&** !(check.substr(i, 1) == "|"))
       {
         cout << "Please enter acceptable barcode.";
         return;
       }
     }
   }
   else
   {
     cout << "else Please enter acceptable barcode";
   }
}
```